# Include file as input stream in scala

Tags: scala, keystore, getresource, javapns

I'm having problems with using a file in my code. I'm working with javaPNS and trying to get it to work. What I think is wrong now is how I get my file for the keystore parameter in the Push.alert method in javaPNS.

What I'm really wondering is how do I "get a resource" properly so it has the correct format?

Here's the exception that is thrown:

```
javapns.communication.exceptions.InvalidKeystoreReferenceException:
Invalid keystore parameter (null).  Must be InputStream, File, String (as a file path),
or byte[].
at........
```

And here's how I currently include the file:

```
val keystoreFile = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/app/conf/cert.p12")
```

If we look at the exception I get, do you think this above is the problem? How should I include the file properly in Scala?

regards,

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing has to do with the fact that the InputStream you are loading is coming back as null. This happens when the file you are trying to load can not be found on the class path.  Try changing your code to:

```
getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("app/conf/cert.p12")
```

You will notice I removed the leading slash on the file path as I believe this is your issue. Then just make sure that whatever the parent directory to "app" is is on your class path.

Comment: Hey thanks, I solved my issue by changing the line `getClass.getResourceAsStream("/app/conf/cert.p12")` to `getClass.getResourceAsStream("/cert.p12")`.

Speaking of something else cmbaxter, I've noticed you've answered quite many of my questions, very good answers for that matter. Are you following me in any way so you can see my questions as soon as I post them? 
I would like to know how if so :)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to follow someone.  I just check the Scala board every couple of hours and if there are questions I think I can answer I try and do so.  I guess it's just a coincidence that I've been able to provide an answer to your questions ;)

Comment: Hehe okey, then I know. Keep up the good work, thanks for providing good educational answers :)